# Main navigation dividers query

Tags: css, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I'm using the following code to style my main navigation with dividers, but for some reason,  the dividers are touching the parallax hero:

```
.main-navigation ul li, .secondary-navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid;
```

}

How do I reduce the width of the divider, so it does not drop down so far?

I've attached a screenshot as evidence. [Picture of dividers and hero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jolaR.png).

Comment: try giving `line-height: 80%`  check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2L3t6skw/

Comment: Thanks for your response. On inspect, that line is getting crossed out. Are you sure that is a valid property?

Comment: Never mind, I put it down twice. When corrected and put in only once it does not effect the dividers.

Comment: yes it is valid. could you post your html or share link

Comment: I've solved this now, line height was the right line but wrong parameters for my page. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with following css:

```
  .main-navigation ul {
    line-height: 7;
  }
```